# How to fix Ajax call "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry........."

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send my data via ajax call to the controller but I check all my code I debug it all values are filled but it continuously shows me this error. event its also show me ON MVC call As Well

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter '**BrandId**' of non-nullable type `'System.Int32'` for method `'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Forms(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase], System.String, Int32, Int32, Boolean, Int32)'`in`'AdminDevVersion.Controllers.HomeController'`. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

i have already debugged the code and I have checked if all the values are filled.

My Ajax Code

```
function uploadSubmitHandler() {
  var PName = $("#ProductName").val();
  var Category = $("#CategoryDropDown").val();
  var Brand = $("#BrandDropDown").val();
  var SubCategory = $("#SubCategory").val();

  var ProductDescription = $('textarea.textarea-editor').val();
  var NewOROldRadio = $("input[name='ProductStatus']:checked").val();
  if (state.fileBatch.length !== 0) {
    var data = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < state.fileBatch.length; i++) {
      data.append('files', state.fileBatch[i].file, state.fileBatch[i].fileName);
    }

    data.append('ProductName', PName);
    data.append('CategoryId', Category);
    data.append('BrandId', Brand);
    data.append('IsNewStatus', NewOROldRadio);
    data.append('SubCategoryId', SubCategory);
    data.append('Description', ProductDescription);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: options.ajaxUrl,
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    });

  }
}
```

Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Forms(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, String ProductName, int CategoryId, int BrandId, bool IsNewStatus, int SubCategoryId)
{
    List<string> FileNames = new List<string>();
    string ImageName = null;
    TblProduct InsertProduct = new TblProduct();
    if (ModelState.IsValid == true)
    {
        InsertProduct.Name = ProductName;
        InsertProduct.IsActive = IsNewStatus;
        InsertProduct.BrdId = BrandId;
        InsertProduct.CatId = SubCategoryId;
        InsertProduct.Image = ImageName;
        InsertProduct.Created = DateTime.Now;
        InsertProduct.IsActive = true;
        _RepoProduct.Insert(InsertProduct);
        _RepoProduct.Save();
        TblProRelImg RelatedImages = new TblProRelImg();
        foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
        {
            string _path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/"), file.FileName);
            file.SaveAs(_path);
            if (file == files.First())
            {
                ImageName = file.FileName.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                RelatedImages.PrdID = InsertProduct.ID;
                RelatedImages.Image = file.FileName;
                _ReporRelatedImages.Insert(RelatedImages);
                _ReporRelatedImages.Save();

            }
            FileNames.Add(file.FileName);
        }
        ViewBag.CategoryId = Logics.Category();
        ViewBag.BrandInfo = new SelectList(DbContext.TblBrands, "Id", "Name");
    }
    return View();
}
```

I have expected to send data to the controller

Comment: Can you show what the debug at the server shows? Whats in the variables?

Comment: there are values of html forms

Comment: What is the return type of `$("#BrandDropDown").val()`? Number or string? Your controller is expecting a number for the `BrandId`. If you want to allow Null then make it nullable int - `int?`

Comment: int & its getting the correct int

Comment: set debugger just before the $.ajax and check data object value. error says your BrandId property is null. and it expect int value

Answer (score 2):

parse your BrandId to int like blow and append to your data

```
parseInt(Brand)
```